# else part is not getting executed , each time its printing "user1 and user2 are equal" even if they are not

Tags: python, python-3.x

class User:
    def **init**(self,name,username,password,mobileNumber):
        self.name=name
        self.username=username
        self.password=password
        self.mobileNumber=mobileNumber

```
def __eq__(self,obj):
    mbno1=User(self.name, self.username,self.password,self.mobileNumber)
    mbno2=User(self.name,self.username,self.password,self.mobileNumber)
    if mbno1.mobileNumber==mbno2.mobileNumber:
       print("user 1 and user 2 are equal")
    else:
       print("user 1 and user 2 are not equal")
```

Comment: both objects have the same values

Comment: I think it would be a great idea to follow a tutorial on classes in Python. It seems you haven't quite grasped that concept yet. This I find is an excellent tutorial on the subject (which includes a section devoted to the keyword "self"):
https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/

Answer (score 0):

This is because in your case both the mobile numbers are always same so the else statement will never be executed.
It is so because self points to the reference of same class and mobno1 & mobno2 both are pointing to same object as both store the data of self so the mobile no are always same.